# I have only one Line in XML and need to set the value of attribute using php

Tags: php, xml

```
<conf id="myrec" mediaplayer="0" up="1" />
```

this is my simple xml. i need to change the value of mediaplayer to 1 from 0. i need the simplest possible way to do that.. file name is new.xml.

I have tried this but didn't work

```
?php

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("New.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("conf");

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
x.item(i).setAttribute("mediaplayer","1");
}

echo $xmlDoc->asXML();

?>
```

Comment: what did happen when you tried above? nothing?

Comment: yes nothing.. but now i have solved this.. i used
 
    $document = simplexml_load_file("New.xml");
    $document['mediaplayer'] = 1;
    $document->asXML("New.xml");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, I used

```
document = simplexml_load_file("New.xml"); $document['mediaplayer'] = 1;  
document->asXML("New.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

use `simplexml` for updating your simple XML ;-)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<conf id="myrec" mediaplayer="0" up="1" />');
$xml['mediaplayer'] = 1;
$xml->asXML("myxml.xml");
```

see it working: http://3v4l.org/P3eMq

EDIT: just seen your comment, you did it!